# Migration weblogic to tomcat : No JTA UserTransaction available

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, tomcat, jta

I work on a multi-module maven application and the weblogic is already in prod. The stack is :

Tomcat 8.5

PostGre 9.6

Hibernate 4.3.8

Spring 4.1.5

Spring Security 3.2.6

Spring Struts 3.2.13

Primes Faces 5.1

I begin to migrate with the creation of a JNDI DataSource in server.xml and a resource link in META-INF/context.xml (we move the DB from DB2 to PostGre) but i got an exception :

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: **No JTA UserTransaction available** - specify either 'userTransaction' or 'userTransactionName' or 'transactionManager' or 'transactionManagerName'

My application is on xml config and i think the error occur beacause JTA implentation was delegate to weblogic in the old version :

**DataSourceContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/mydatasourcename" />
</bean>

<bean id="hibernateProperties"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="properties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.query.substitutions">true=1 false=0</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">1</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.default_schema">defaultschemaname</prop>
            <!-- How to find the Transaction -->
            <prop key="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.CMTTransactionFactory
            </prop>

            <!-- How to produce transaction -->

            **<prop key="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform">org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.WeblogicJtaPlatform
            </prop>**

            <!-- Session context with JTA -->
            <prop key="current_session_context_class">jta</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

**My Tomcat DataSource :**

```
<GlobalNamingResources>
<!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
     UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
-->
    <Resource auth="Container" description="User database that can be updated and saved" factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory" name="UserDatabase" pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" readonly="true" type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"/>
    <Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver" 
         maxIdle="10"
         maxTotal="20"
         maxWaitMillis="10000" 
         name="jdbc/*****" 
         password="*****" 
         type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
         url="jdbc:postgresql://********:5432/****" 
         username="****"/>  
</GlobalNamingResources>
```

**Hibernate Config applicationContextDAO.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">


    <bean id="mySessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
              <value>package.name</value>
            </list>
        </property> 
        <property name="annotatedPackages">
            <list>
                <value>package.name</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties" ref="hibernateProperties" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="saveHibernateListener" class="package.name.hibernateListener.SaveHibernateListener"/>

    <bean id="customEditorConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomEditorConfigurer">
        <property name="propertyEditorRegistrars">
            <list>
                <bean class="package.name.CustomDateEditorRegistrar"/>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

<!-- Template hibernate injecté dans chaque persisteur -->
    <bean id="hibernateTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**Facade module applicationContext-transaction.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">

```
<tx:advice id="txAdvice">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="get*" propagation="REQUIRED" read-only="true"
            rollback-for="ExceptionWork" />
        <tx:method name="*" propagation="REQUIRED" rollback-for="MessageException" />
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>

<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="ivaFacadePointcut"
        expression="execution(* package.name..*.*(..))" />
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="FacadePointcut" />
</aop:config>

<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>

<tx:jta-transaction-manager />
<tx:annotation-driven/>
```

---

I think i have to replace this prop in DataSourceContext.xml :
org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.WeblogicJtaPlatform  ?

**An existing clean solution to implement a Transaction Manager in tomcat 8.5?** Or a standalone Transaction Manager?

I'm confused about all solution i already found(old version of hibernate or depreciated implementation of JTA)...if someone can enlight me i will appreciate :)

Answer (score 0):

While Weblogic is a full Application Server, Tomcat is in the hand only a web container. Due to that you need to close a few gaps between those two.

A transaction manager is one of them. Weblogic will "automatically" add one for you while Tomcat doesn't have the ability to do so.

If you use something like the snippet below you should be able to get past this problem.

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks for your support, i still have the same execption. The actual config seem to wait for a JTA transaction Manager. I will edit my post with the transaction xml config.

Comment: Try using org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager instead of the Jpa one in my answer

Comment: thats a good idea, i found they use this one on the test side of the project : <!-- Transcation manager -->
 <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
  <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory" />
 </bean>

Comment: The problem you're having is you'r tx manager is not properly setup for Tomcat... Unfortunately I'm a bit busy with work right now and can't quite give you a full working example. Your HibernateTransactionManager should work just fine with Tomcat so you can just replace the Jta one for the hibernate one

Comment: Thanks again, i will explore this way.